# question about seperate materials

Tags: materials

want to ask a simple thing that when I separate the one face of the cube and now want to apply the material to only that one face but it's applying on the whole cube any reason what I am doing wrong
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zo1Y.png

Comment: I suggest learn how to apply materials in general: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) Also please make your question title more specific, read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post